# How to create custom_modules for third-party-packages with modifications?

Tags: react-native, node-modules, patch-package

I have done some changes to the files inside the Pods Folder of Third-party Package and I want to store them with the project but when i run the `pod install` command, the changes revert backs to original one. Any idea will be appreciated.

I have tried to patch the package but it only patches the changes to the package(inside the node_modules) and not the pods.

Comment: you have to create a PR to the thirdparty package modifying what you want to change

Comment: creating custom_modules for this will help? @EduardoPalacio

Answer (score 1):

To preserve your local changes to a third-party package in the Pods folder, follow these steps:

- **Fork repository:**
  Go to the GitHub repo & click on the **"Fork"** button at the top-right corner to create a copy of the repository under your GitHub account.
- **Clone forked repository:**
  Open a terminal or command prompt on your local machine & clone the forked repository to your computer.
- **Update the Code:**
  Make the necessary changes/update to the package codebase and update dependencies if required.
- **Use updated forked package:**
  Now import your forked package as a new package into the project.
  *(You can also generate PR request for contribute to others developers)*

Open the Podfile in a text editor and Add the following line to include the pod from the forked repository:

```
target 'Runner' do
  # ... other pods ...

  pod 'YourForkedPod', :git => 'https://github.com/YourGitHubUsername/YourForkedPod.git', :branch => 'branch_name_if_needed'

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much...I'll do the steps you specified.